# Magento - adding a widget instance to a template file

Tags: magento

I know that you can call a cms block directly from a template file using the following:

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('footer_links')->toHtml() ?>
```

Is there some way to do this with widget instances?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In your template:

```
<?php
$filter = Mage::getModel('widget/template_filter');
echo $filter->filter('{{widget type="cms/widget_page_link" template="cms/widget/link/link_block.phtml" page_id="2"}}');
?>
```

Comment: Great - to grab a product link it's: <?php
$filter = new Mage_Widget_Model_Template_Filter();
$_widget = $filter->filter('{{widget type="catalog/product_widget_link" template="cms/widget/link/link_block.phtml" id_path="product/16"}}');
echo $_widget;
?>

Comment: Doesn't seem to work in 1.8.1, code breaks on $_widget = $filter... line.

Answer (score 5):

Andrew missed toHtml() function at the end:

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/widget_page_link')->setTemplate('cms/widget/link/link_block.phtml')->setPageId(2)->toHtml(); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

To know the correct parameters "type", "template" and more, you can use the "Insert widget" button on the graphical editor in a block/page template, then you click the show/hide editor and you get the code

Answer (score 2):

The answer above may work, but the same thing can be achieved by loading the widget as you would a static block and passing in the custom parameters using the magic setters like this:

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/widget_page_link')->setTemplate('cms/widget/link/link_block.phtml')->setPageId(2); ?>
```

Comment: Strange, this doesn't work for me on Mage 1.6.2.0, Japhet's answer does though